# How does REST API maintain authorization at the client side?

Tags: rest, api, authorization, client-server

Suppose I have a API service, with the endpoint abc.com/api. Now, a client has a CLIENT_ID which is included in the URL (eg: abc.com/api/name=Hello&CLIENT_ID=xxx) used for authorization of the client on the server side. After authorization, the API sends back the response. 
But, it may also happen that this particular url is intercepted in between, which exposes the CLIENT_ID. My question is, how does the Rest API ensure that client is authorized, and sends response to only the authorized client, that is me. Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HTTPS, your requests are mostly protected from an "interception" or a man-in-the-middle attack because the data will be encrypted. However authorization tokens are typically not included as query parameters because URLs are logged in various places on the client and server side, reducing the level of security. Instead, authorization data is usually included in HTTP headers (often as cookies).

Comment: Is there any way to enforce authorization using HTTP only?

Comment: There is no industry-standard way. The industry-standard is to use HTTPS for all sensitive communication. At this point, HTTPS is used for almost all non-sensitive communication too.